# Can't find my post after re-tagging, do I need to re-post?

Tags: discussion, support, status-norepro, tags

I have submitted a question on Stack Overflow, initially with 3 tags [Python], [SQLAlchemy] and [ORM]. There was very little response on the question, and in retrospect the question was more of a general programming question than having to do specifically with Python or SQLalchemy.

So I added the [MVC] and [design-patterns] tags, with the intent of having people that follow those specific tags to have a look at the problem.
However, when I navigate to those groups, I can't seem to find my question.

I was wondering if adding these tags actually does what I expected (bring my question under the attention of those specific groups of people) or if I need to re-submit my question with different tags in the first place?

Thanks,

Erik

Comment: I assume it is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890318/how-to-setup-a-3-tier-web-application-project

Comment: Correct, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the question in both tag pages.

It was asked on the 19th of September, so it is down the list.

Comment: So it does make the question appear under these categories, but it is further down the list because of the original post date?

Comment: @RicoSuave - yes. When in the "newest" tab, questions are sorted by the original post date.

Comment: Thanks Oded. Is it acceptable to repost a question with new tags to get it under the attention of the newly added groups, or is it bad practice?

Comment: @RicoSuave If you edit your question, add update information, progress etc. it will be on the top in the active tab again, so this is a way to get attention. Additionally you can put a bounty on it

Comment: @RicoSuave - Don't repost a duplicate. Improve the existing one. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions